# Twitter Bootstrap not recognizing class set through Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, class, twitter-bootstrap, attributes

I'm a very seasoned writer of JavaScript, so I like to experiment in weird ways to further understand how things work. I've attempted to write an application that works using angular.js and Twitter Bootstrap, yet I am creating all of my elements via JavaScript, not hard-coding them into HTML (I hate writing HTML). So far, everything appears to be working fine, except that Bootstrap will not recognize a class list that I've attached to a table element via JavaScript. Here's a quick snippet example:

```
var myTbl = document.createElement('table');
myTbl.setAttribute('class', 'table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed');
```

The table is created just fine and the class is viewable as an atrribute in the debugger, yet the styles associated to this class list are not being applied to the table via Bootstrap.
I've tried including Bootstrap before I called the function which builds this table as well as I've tried including Bootstrap after I build this table, and this did not make any difference. I am also including angular.min.js after constructing this table and after including Bootstrap. I've also written the same application in HTML, associated an ID to the table with the class, and later pulled that table into a JavaScript variable to investigate it within the debugger, and it is exactly identical to the JavaScript generated table, yet the hard-coded HTML table has the style effects of the class list and the JavaScript generated one does not. If anyone can help me out, it would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: looks fine to me:http://jsfiddle.net/93RLp/2/

Comment: So weird? Why does it work for you but not for me...  :(

Comment: did you inspect the results iframe from the fiddle? take a look at the order of the what's being loaded. jquery.js, bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css, the style in the fiddle, then the javascript in the fiddle

Comment: Hmmm, this is interesting... Thanks man

Comment: This appears to be browser specific, as well as element type specific. I am having issues with this in chrome, yet not IE. Not sure what the issue is.